# Frequency from fft data set matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency, axis-labels

I have a data set in a matrix in matlab. It contains 25,000 values taken every 0.5 ns; so the total time of the dataset is 1.25E-5 seconds.

The data set contains very high frequency noise that I am not interested in so I create another matrix is every 50th data point from the first matrix So the size of the matrix is 1000*.

I plot the absolute values from matlab's fft this matrix (I also normalise the amplitude and only plot the first half) and get the attached (two plots, second is a close up of the low frequencies I am interested in). How do I convert the x-axis to frequency?

- Another point, if I take every data point (so I create an fft of the entire 25,000 points) then the x-axis is exactly the same; in other words, the size of my matrix seems to have no bearing on the x-axis returned by matlab. I've attached two links to the frequency spectrum, one of which is a close-up of the low frequencies I am interested in. It's axis goes from 0-50, so it is these values I need to convert to Hz.

Thankyou in advance!

[Close up of frequency spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuovJ.png)

[frequency spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b71VT.png)

Answer (score 0):

From what I read on http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/fast-fourier-transform-fft.html#bresqop-1, it appears that the units on the x-axis of the plotted FFT are Hz if the first vector, `f`, you put into the `plot(f,power)`, is defined as a sequence of `n` elements (`n` being the number of data points put into the FFT) increasing from zero to the sample frequency.

Thus, for the first plot, which used every 50th of points that were taken at a frequency of 2 GHz, the sample frequency would be 40 MHz. Thus, `f = (0:n-1)*4*10^7/(25000/50)`

It goes on to show how to use the `fftshift` function to put the center of the output of the `fft` function at 0, but it's clear you already did that and chopped off the negative part.

So, once you have the right separation of `fs/n`, sampling frequency divided by number of data points used, in the vector that supplies the x-axis to the `plot` function, then the units of the x-axis will be Hz.

(I hope you still have the numbers to graph again? If not, this question might help: [Confusion in figuring out the relation between actual frequency values and FFT plot indexes in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721827/confusion-in-figuring-out-the-relation-between-actual-frequency-values-and-fft-p?rq=1))